# problema al mostrar datos en laravel con una consulta

Tags: sql, laravel

```
 public static function actividad_inicio_get()
    {

        $actividades= actividades::all();
        $gerencia=gerencia::all()->pluck('ga','id');

en esta parte realizo la consulta de la tabla unidades lo que quiero es 
comparar el id de la consulta gerencia con el id que guarde en la tabla 
unidades
que esta relacionada ya y el campo es ge y si es igual que me muestre todos 
los nombres que estan en la variable unidad y de ahi guardar el 
resultado 
en $ue para mandarlo a la vista y que me lo muestre

        $ue = \DB::table('unidades')->where('ge', $gerencia)->get();

        return \View::make('actividades',compact('gerencia'),compact('ue'))->with(
            [
                'actividades' => $actividades,
                'contador' => 0
            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: Que error obtienes?

Answer (score 0):

**Opcion 1**

```
return view('actividades')->with(['actividades'=>$actividades, 'gerencia'=>$gerencia, 'ue'=>$ue, 'contador'=>$contador]);
```

**Opcion 2**

`return view('actividades')->with(compact('actividades','gerencia','ue','contador`');

**Opcion 3**

```
$data = [
'actividades'=>$actividades,
'gerencia'=>$gerencia,
'ue'=>$ue,
'contador'=>0
];

return View::make('actividades', $data);
```